# Cannot find my schemas in QGIS's "Add PostGIS layers"

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0

When I connect to my PostGIS database using QGIS's `Add PostGIS Layers`, I see only

```
public
topology
pg_catalog
information_schema
```

My other schemas that I have created are not shown here. Anyone else experiencing the same problem? I'm using QGIS v1.8.0-Lisboa, PostgreSQL-9.1 and PostGIS-2.0.1

How should I go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: Some more detail might help, though on the surface, it looks like a permissions issue.  Have you granted permissions to all of the schemas that you are trying to access using this particular user?  The only schemas, tables, etc., that will show are the ones that the user in question has permission to read.

Comment: If these schemas only contain non-spatial tables, you might want to try telling QGIS to also list non-spatial tables. I think schemas are hidden if there are no tables to display.

Comment: What does 'show search_path;' (in pgAdmin or at the command line) give you??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the user you're using to connect to you postgresql db doesn't have permissions to view the schema.

You can check more info about the permissions [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-alterschema.html) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-grant.html)